# Loop over nested JSON elements in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I am receiving a JSON response from an API that contains one or more "entities". The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "3211": {
        "entity_id": "3211",
        "status": "complete",
        "coupon_code": "COUPON",
        "shipping_description": "Shipping - AU Courier",
        "customer_id": "2775",
        "base_discount_amount": "-50.0000",
        "base_grand_total": "149.0000",
        "base_shipping_amount": "0.0000",
        "base_shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
        "base_subtotal": "199.0000",
        "base_tax_amount": "0.0000",
        "base_total_paid": "149.0000",
        "base_total_refunded": null,
        "discount_amount": "-50.0000",
        "grand_total": "149.0000",
        "shipping_amount": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
        "store_to_order_rate": "1.0000",
        "subtotal": "199.0000",
        "tax_amount": "0.0000",
        "total_paid": "149.0000",
        "total_refunded": null,
        "base_shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
        "base_subtotal_incl_tax": "199.0000",
        "base_total_due": "0.0000",
        "shipping_discount_amount": "0.0000",
        "subtotal_incl_tax": "199.0000",
        "total_due": "0.0000",
        "increment_id": "200000423",
        "base_currency_code": "AUD",
        "discount_description": "COUPON",
        "remote_ip": "123.123.123.123",
        "store_currency_code": "AUD",
        "store_name": "Australia",
        "created_at": "2017-07-17 03:07:40",
        "shipping_incl_tax": "0.0000",
        "payment_method": "ewayrapid_ewayone",
        "gift_message_from": null,
        "gift_message_to": null,
        "gift_message_body": null,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "addresses": [
            {
                "region": "South Australia",
                "postcode": "5000",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "street": "Level 6\n25 Example Street",
                "city": "Adelaide",
                "email": "example@email.com",
                "telephone": "+61 123 456 789",
                "country_id": "AU",
                "firstname": "John",
                "address_type": "billing",
                "prefix": null,
                "middlename": null,
                "suffix": null,
                "company": null
            },
            {
                "region": "South Australia",
                "postcode": "5000",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "street": "Level 6\n25 Example Street",
                "city": "Adelaide",
                "email": "example@email.com",
                "telephone": "+61 123 456 789",
                "country_id": "AU",
                "firstname": "John",
                "address_type": "shipping",
                "prefix": null,
                "middlename": null,
                "suffix": null,
                "company": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have written the following `struct` types:

```
type Orders map[string]Order
type Order struct {
    EntityID                   string                    `json:"entity_id"`
    Status                     string                    `json:"status"`
    CouponCode                 string                    `json:"coupon_code"`
    ShippingDescription        string                    `json:"shipping_description"`
    CustomerID                 string                    `json:"customer_id"`
    BaseDiscountAmount         string                    `json:"base_discount_amount"`
    BaseGrandTotal             string                    `json:"base_grand_total"`
    BaseShippingAmount         string                    `json:"base_shipping_amount"`
    BaseShippingTaxAmount      string                    `json:"base_shipping_tax_amount"`
    BaseSubtotal               string                    `json:"base_subtotal"`
    BaseTaxAmount              string                    `json:"base_tax_amount"`
    BaseTotalPaid              string                    `json:"base_total_paid"`
    BaseTotalRefunded          string                    `json:"base_total_refunded"`
    DiscountAmount             string                    `json:"discount_amount"`
    GrandTotal                 string                    `json:"grand_total"`
    ShippingAmount             string                    `json:"shipping_amount"`
    ShippingTaxAmount          string                    `json:"shipping_tax_amount"`
    StoreToOrderRate           string                    `json:"store_to_order_rate"`
    Subtotal                   string                    `json:"subtotal"`
    TaxAmount                  string                    `json:"tax_amount"`
    TotalPaid                  string                    `json:"total_paid"`
    TotalRefunded              string                    `json:"total_refunded"`
    BaseShippingDiscountAmount string                    `json:"base_shipping_discount_amount"`
    BaseSubtotalInclTax        string                    `json:"base_subtotal_incl_tax"`
    BaseTotalDue               string                    `json:"base_total_due"`
    ShippingDiscountAmount     string                    `json:"shipping_discount_amount"`
    SubtotalInclTax            string                    `json:"subtotal_incl_tax"`
    TotalDue                   string                    `json:"total_due"`
    IncrementID                string                    `json:"increment_id"`
    BaseCurrencyCode           string                    `json:"base_currency_code"`
    DiscountDescription        string                    `json:"discount_description"`
    RemoteIP                   string                    `json:"remote_ip"`
    StoreCurrencyCode          string                    `json:"store_currency_code"`
    StoreName                  string                    `json:"store_name"`
    CreatedAt                  string                    `json:"created_at"`
    ShippingInclTax            string                    `json:"shipping_incl_tax"`
    PaymentMethod              string                    `json:"payment_method"`
    TaxName                    string                    `json:"tax_name"`
    TaxRate                    string                    `json:"tax_rate"`
    Addresses                  map[string]OrderAddresses `json:"addresses"`
}

type OrderAddresses []struct {
    Region      string  `json:"region"`
    Postcode    string  `json:"postcode"`
    Lastname    string  `json:"lastname"`
    Street      string  `json:"street"`
    City        string  `json:"city"`
    Email       string  `json:"email"`
    Telephone   string  `json:"telephone"`
    CountryID   string  `json:"country_id"`
    Firstname   string  `json:"firstname"`
    AddressType string  `json:"address_type"`
    Prefix      *string `json:"prefix"`
    Middlename  *string `json:"middlename"`
    Suffix      *string `json:"suffix"`
    Company     *string `json:"company"`
}
```

I am then trying to process it like so (the `getFromOrdersAPI(page)` function returns the JSON mentioned above in the `Orders` type):

```
for page := 1; page < 3; page++ {
    orders := getFromOrdersAPI(page)
    for _, order := range orders {
        //Process all the order items except addresses
        fmt.Println("Processing entity:", orders.EntityID)

        for _, orderaddress := range order.Addresses {
            //Trying to access address values - example below
            fmt.Println(orderaddress.Region)
        }
    }
}
```

When running this, I get the error:

> orderaddress.Region undefined (type OrderAddresses has no field or method Region)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the way you are defining your `OrderAddresses` struct. Instead of

```
type OrderAddresses []struct {
```

If you use

```
type OrderAddresses struct {
```

without the braces, your compile error should go away.

That being said, I'm not sure if your json will parse as you expect given the blob I'm looking at. It appears that `addresses` in the json blob is an array. This means that instead of representing it as

```
Addresses map[string]OrderAddresses `json:"addresses"`
```

You should simply make it a slice of `OrderAddresses`

```
Addresses []OrderAddresses `json:"addresses"`
```

Comment: Thanks Vikram, your explanation helped a lot. I've recently shifted to Go from PHP and am still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the `orderaddress.Region undefined` error is because the `orderaddress` in your `for` loop is an array, based on your `OrderAddresses` type. Obviously, an array doesn't have fields or methods named `Region`.

If you want to examine what `orderaddress` in your `for` loop looks like, you can `range` over it like this:

```
for _, orderaddress := range order.Addresses {
  for _, addressData := range orderaddress{
      fmt.Printf("%+v\n", addressData)
  }
}
```

I have created an example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/jcTc05sMfz).

That said, in your JSON data, the `addresses` field is an array, not a map. So the `Addresses` field in your `Order` struct must be an array too. Then your `OrderAddresses` should just be a struct, not a slice of struct.